# How to center DIV on the middle of the page

Tags: html, css

I've been trying so many different ways on trying to center the ingredients with the middle of the page and it just hasn't been working out. When I add text-align: Center; to the "Ingredients" class, the ingredients do move towards the middle but they aren't aligned with each other, if that makes sense. Any way I can center the ingredients and have them aligned? An example of what happens when I use text-align: center; is below. Also, I am a novice on programming lol, just slowly learning through The Odin Project. Thank you.

HTML:

```
<div class="border">
    <div class="ingredients">
        <input type="checkbox" name="ingredients" id="sausage" value="sausage">
        <label for="sausage">1 pound sweet italian sausage</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.ingredients{
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 30px;
}
```

[CSS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yByWH.png)

[Screenshot of page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C9qBa.jpg)

[Example of text-align](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yC6Iu.png)

[HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9nBmG.png)

Comment: ciao, bro please write the code, not send the images

Comment: so you want that they to be centered, but the input stays in the same column?

Comment: yes, so centered and the checkbox's aligned with each other

Comment: Adding this helped, but would it be consistent?                                                                                                                  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 575px;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;

Answer (score 1):

Use flexbox for this.

```css
.ingredients{
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 30px;
}

.border{
   display:flex;
   justify-content:center;
   align-items:center;
   height:100vh;
   
   }
   
   body, html{
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   }
```

```html
<div class="border">
    <div class="ingredients">
        <input type="checkbox" name="ingredients" id="sausage" value="sausage">
        <label for="sausage">1 pound sweet italian sausage</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**using CSS GRID**

[image]

as you can see I tried to use multiple inputs, 
from the smaller text to the bigger text, 
 so they will be working fine on a Real-Scenario of your project (also with different lenghts).

so by using a grid layout they will be responsive with the minimum code needed!

```css
grid-template-columns: auto 1fr; /* for making the inputs aligned one under the other */
place-items: center start;       /* for solving the bug about the positioning of text (label)*/
```

> useful documentations: 
> **- CSS `grid`:** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Grid_Layout 
> **- `grid-template-columns`** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-columns 
> **- `place-items`**: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/place-items 
> **- `gap`:** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gap

**the code used in the image of before:**

```css
.border {
    /* parent container, for centering the child */
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
}

.ingredients {
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 30px;
    /* using grid layout */
    display: grid;
    /* all the child always have the same space (the bigger element width) */
    grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
    /* centering the text vertically, but is in the start one under the other */
    place-items: center start;
    /* a gap between the input and the text */
    gap: 0 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="border">
        <div class="ingredients">
            <!-- delete the BR tags -->
            <input type="checkbox" name="ingredients" id="sausage" value="sausage">
            <label for="sausage">1</label>

            <input type="checkbox" name="ingredients" id="sausage" value="sausage">
            <label for="sausage">1 pound </label>

            <input type="checkbox" name="ingredients" id="sausage" value="sausage">
            <label for="sausage">1 pound sweet </label>

            <input type="checkbox" name="ingredients" id="sausage" value="sausage">
            <label for="sausage">1 pound sweet italian</label>

            <input type="checkbox" name="ingredients" id="sausage" value="sausage">
            <label for="sausage">1 pound sweet italian sausage</label>
        </div>
    </div>
```